# SELECT WHERE (`a` unequal '0') in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have:

```
`a` int DEFAULT '0'
```

From the thousands of records I have, I want to choose the ones that **do not have** a value of 0 or empty in `a`.

I tried something like this.

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (`a` unequal '0' or '') ;"
```

Comment: Search for COALESCE ;)

Comment: @Stu My English is not good, irrelevant answers come when I search. Please write me a very detailed answer below. I promise to give you 50 points ...

Comment: relevant [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-equal-operator.php) link

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(a,0) FROM table will replace the null values by zero. How to check unequal was linked above by Stu. Can you put this together in a correct query?

Comment: You can likely find tons of information in any language, in a very different ways. I.E.: `WHERE a <> '0' or a <> ''`, `WHERE a !=  '0' or a != ''`, `WHERE a not in ('0','')`...  tons

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (`a` <>'0' or `a` = '' or `a` is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without giving away the answer:

Your WHERE clause is wrong. When you make multiple comparisons, you need to define which variable is being compared each time. It needs to be

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE a<>'whatever'
OR <>'whatever2'
```

Comment: You should give the answer...otherwise they would be called clues.